# Summing similar values with a list using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following value in a list by

```
Feb 13  100 
Feb 13  150 
Feb 13  127 
Feb 14  50
```

using linq how do I return another list with the sum for each date including the previous days total?

e.g

```
Feb 13 357  (Sum of Feb 13)   
Feb 14 407  (Sum of Feb 14 + Sum of Feb 13)
```

with some mucking about

```
list= list.OrderBy(i => i.date)
                    .Distinct().Select(
                i =>
                    {
                        np+= i.rh;
                        nh+= i.hm;
                        return new Po
                            {
                                date= i.date,
                                NH =  nh,

                            };
                    }).ToList();
```

this return this list:

```
Feb 13  100 
Feb 13  250 
Feb 13  377 
Feb 14  427
```

I would like just

```
 Feb 13 357  
 Feb 14 407
```

Comment: Have you tried something already that we could discuss? Or you are waiting for someone else writing the code for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
decimal runningTotal = 0;
var result = from item in items
             orderby item.Date
             group items by item.Date into grp
             let sum = items.Where(x => x.Date == grp.Key).Sum(x => x.Amount)
             select new
             {
                 Date = grp.Key,
                 Sum = runningTotal += sum,
             };
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Happy Valentine day lol.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this if you know the values ahead

```
   var Total = listval.Sum(od => od.vall)+listval.where(od => od.date=="Feb 13").Sum(od =>
 od.vall)+listval.where(od => od.date=="Feb 14").Sum(od => od.vall);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by grouping the objects and using the Sum within the group.  The link Mark posted shows exactly how to do that.